# Use-case specification of included use-case

Tags: uml, use-case

Does anyone know how to describe (specify) the use-case that includes another usecase in the use-case specification table?
For example, I have a use-case "change password" that includes use-case "login" (this is just an example, i know that login should just be in the pre-condition of the use-case)
May i specify it like this?

---

Use-case identity: Change password

Actor: User

Pre-condition: ...

Normal flow:

1. Do use-case "Login"
2. ....
3. ....
4. ....

   ---

What is the proper way to specify the use-case that includes another use-case?

Comment: This is a non-coding question and as such it is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on this site. For questions about software requirements, development methodologies and processes etc. there is the [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) site

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the further rules and conventions used together with the "use-case specification table" document. Consult your company documents for the rules (and some examples).

Overall **yes**, your approach is valid.

The "Login" use case might be also invoked implicitly if you'd move it to the "Pre-condition: User is logged-in"

Even for free text without any Software Requirements Management tool consider using the "Name and unique-number" referencing best practice

To wrap your head around it I'd recommend (among other Google-able resources) to read the Alistair Cockburn's book "Writing Effective Use Cases", draft version is available online on his site - http://alistair.cockburn.us/get/2465

---

**EDIT: after @BobRodes's challenge to share some alternative methodology**

For more serious work consider using a [Requirements Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirements_management) tool, or at least evaluate some tools to adopt the best practices they support/recommend.

For one example see the link below explaining how Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect formalizes work with Use Cases and how Use Case traceability works and how it can generate documentation, UML Activity Diagram etc.

> [Sparx Systems: Model-Driven Use Case Analysis with Structured Scenarios, Webinar August 2013](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/demos/use-case-analysis/model-driven-use-case-analysis-with-structured-scenarios.html), 18min video
>
> [image]

For another example of managing Use Case traceability and what usually happens after the Use Cases are written see

> [Jama Software: Jama Recorded Demo](http://www.jamasoftware.com/jama-recorded-demo/), 30min video
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into "use case narrative".  In such a narrative, one of the things you will do is list included use cases and extension points.  So, add a section called "Includes:" to your narrative, before the normal flow section.

Edit: Here's a bit more from Tom Pender's "The UML Bible":

> The features of a use case narrative aren't standardized, but these
>   are common elements in wide use:
>
> - Use case initiation, or trigger, describes how to start a use case.
> - Assumptions define conditions that must be true before the use case may execute, but are not tested  by the use case.
> - Preconditions define conditions that must be true before the use    case may execute, and are tested by  the use case.
> - The use case dialog explains how the user (whether an actor or    another use case) interacts with the system during the execution of
>     the use case.
> - Use case terminations define the different mechanisms that can    cause the use case to stop execution.
> - Post conditions define the state of the system that must be true    when the use case ends. This helps  prevent use cases from leaving
>     the system in an unstable condition for other use cases that follow.
> - Minimum guarantees describe what the actors can expect from a use    case, no matter what happens  during the execution of the use case.
> - Successful guarantees describe what the actors can expect from a    use case when it completes  successfully.
>
> Although these elements are valuable, they are by no means exclusive.
>   Definitely look into other books and online resources on use cases,
>   and augment the narrative to support your own method of  development.

So, perhaps I shouldn't have said that you "will" list included use cases and extension points, instead saying that you "may" do so.  I like to put them in, so I don't have to keep referring back to the diagrams to look them up.  Of course, you can just mention them in the dialog, too.

Comment: Looking into "_use case narrative_" through Google shows **17 million pages**. What **exactly** do you mean? Where does your conclusion "_So, add a section.._" come from? Any "formal" use case narrative specification? There is no such word in http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/Superstructure/PDF neither in http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/Infrastructure/PDF neither in http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/PDF

Comment: The first link that comes up in that 17 million is a fairly good explanation of use case narratives.  If you wish to look at a detailed explanation of exactly what I mean, look [here](http://www.amazon.com/UML-Bible-Tom-Pender/dp/0764526049).  The UML spec doesn't address any sort of formal documenting methodology to accompany use case diagrams, so exactly what you do to document them is more a matter of convention and practice than formal theoretical specification. If you have an alternative methodology that you find superior in your experience, by all means share it.

Comment: I did a little more digging around and [this](http://idb.snu.ac.kr/images/1/12/UML_Weekend_Crash_Course_Session7.ppt) is a pretty succinct explanation.

Comment: Your first "here" (Tom Pender's book UML Bible, 2003) is not free information source, the use case narrative was not in my set of preview-able pages. Your second "this" (Tom Pender's presentation UML Weekend Crash Course, Building the Use Case Narrative) uses UML use case diagram but not a section called "includes:" with list of use cases. Do you know of any other credible source supporting that your answer is the "_proper way to specify the use-case that includes another use-case_"? (BTW: I have updated my answer after your comment)

Comment: There isn't a hard-and-fast formal use case narrative specification by some sort of OMG-like body.  From Tom's book: "...the Use Case diagram is usually accompanied by a set of use case descriptions, also called use case narratives. While the form of the narrative is not standard, there are many helpful templates available..."  [Here](https://archive.org/stream/WILEYUMLBible2003/WILEY%20-%20UML%20Bible%20%282003%29_djvu.txt) is a text-only version of the book online.

Answer (score 0):

In UML there is standard relationship named include. Start relationship from including UseCase and end on included UseCase. See UseCase section of UML Superstructure document. [UML website](http://www.uml.org)