# Is use case narrative part of the UML?

Tags: uml

Is use case narrative part of the UML?

A textual description of the business event and how the user will interact with the system to accomplish the task.

Comment: What is a "user case"?

Comment: any user case's narrative can be part of the UML

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. Maybe you try google translate?

Comment: it's use case @thomas,i'm sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, UML means **Unified Modelling Language**. It is a language which helps in designing and modelling software systems. So use case is not a part of UML. UML is a tool that helps to represent Use Cases (Among other things).  And Use Case Modelling is an approach in requirement engineering for **understanding and describing the functional requirements of a System.**

It can be both **narrative and graphical**. Textual representation part is called use case specification while the graphical representation part is called Use case diagram. 
[image]

So what is a use case?
 **A use case is a summary of scenarios for a single task or a goal** like "pay bill" in the above image. And a Use case model typically consists of several use cases. It helps to provide a clear picture about the external actors (both users and external systems),the functional requirements of the system and the relationships among them which in turn leads to a better design.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that you mean "use case narrative." That given, the short answer to your question is "no."

A "use case narrative" is a document that describes the entire behavior of a use case. The UML doesn't define documentation methodologies specifically, so this isn't part of the UML specification.

The UML community has yet to build any sort of consensus on a term for this document (and, indeed, exactly what it ought to contain). Nipun Sampath, in his answer, calls it a "use case specification," for example, and muszeo calls it a "textual description," which, of course, it is.

The behavior of a use case would be modeled in UML as an activity diagram. So, an activity diagram is a diagram of a use case narrative.

For more information on use case narratives, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328336/use-case-specification-of-included-use-case).

Comment: Honestly, that PDF you refer to is a very bad one (starts with in-/exclude promoting functional decomposition; bad coloring; "login" as use case (argh!)). Better one reads Bittner/Spence about UCs.

Comment: @ThomasKilian No, it isn't well written, is it? I only read the section on use case narratives. Most of the examples I've been able to find (including, if I'm not mistaken, Bittner/Spence) generally use the term "use case description" rather than "use case narrative." Tom Pender, who taught me UML when I was learning it, uses the latter term. Anyway, I've edited my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'd guess that "narrative" isn't set in concrete so one can use "description" alternatively without harm.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Exactly. Pender mentions in his book that they are also referred to as use case descriptions. I just wanted to stick with the OP's term to avoid possibly further confusing him.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you mean Use Case, rather than User Case. The description you give (textual description of steps to accomplish a business task using a system) is broadly what Use Cases are about.

To be clear, a Use Case is a kind of *functional requirement*; namely a description of a **process** that a person and/or system (**role**(s)) performs with **information** to accomplish an **objective** that has business value. With Use Cases this specification generally starts with a model ('blobs on a page') which illustrates the process, system and actor (role) context, with a textual description and/or supporting models (e.g. Activity Diagrams) to express the steps of the process. There are other ways to express functional requirements -- User Stories and BPMN process charts are two other examples that achieve the same thing but in different ways. You may be confusing Use Cases and User Stories, perhaps.